# Detect if directory exists in .htaccess before using rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using this `.htaccess` rule to detect the username in the URL, and redirect the visitor to the user profile page:

```
# username handler
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,30})$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

So that:

`example.com/asantos` opens `user.php?username=asantos`

I also have first level directories:

- `example.com/ajax/`
- `example.com/static/`
- `example.com/assets/`

So, if I open any of those directories directly, they get detected by the htaccess rule, and thus is redirected to:

- `example.com/user.php?username=ajax`
- `example.com/user.php?username=static`
- `example.com/user.php?username=assets`

How can I ignore that `.htaccess` rule when, and only when, the directory already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,30})$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Or, for better performance, list the directories to avoid polling the filesystem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(?:ajax|static|assets)$
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,30})$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]
```